# Django 1.5 is finally insecure?

Tags: python, django, security, versioning, django-1.5

I am django user and using 1.5 version and almost finish developing application.
But I finally realized that whenever I read the documents of django 1.5 there is a banner on the top that 1.5 is insecure version.. Should I have to move to higher version?

Comment: You don't have to upgrade but 1.6 brings new transactions and 1.7 brings an improved, built-in South so if only you can upgrade (time, costs, etc.), don't hesitate to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The message is there because of the [Django's release process](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/release-process/#supported-versions) philosophy:

> The rule of thumb is that fixes will be backported to the last major
>   release for bugs that would have prevented a release in the first
>   place (release blockers).
>
> Security fixes and data loss bugs will be applied to the current
>   master, the last two major releases, and the current LTS release.

Since Django 1.7 is now got finally stable, current and new security problems would be fixed in 1.6, 1.7 and the latest [`LTS` release](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/release-process/#long-term-support-lts-releases) 1.4. This is why 1.5 is considered "insecure".

---

There is also a related detailed article being posted this week:

- [Django Versioning](http://andrewsforge.com/article/upgrading-django-to-17/part-1-introduction-and-django-releases/#django-versioning)